# How to schedule a jar file on Linux for fixed time in future?

Tags: linux, shell, jar

I need to run a jar file (`datacollector.jar`), say having path (`/home/vagrant/datatool`) on a Linux machine for a fixed interval of time. For example, from 18:00 10-06-2017 to 03:00 11-06-2017 in some future time. After that, the process should be killed.

I want to write a shell script for this which takes two arguments *starting* and *ending* time.

The script should also inform if its already running or not, and I should be able to manually stop it before ending time.

I am unable to figure this out after spending some researching online. How can I achieve this?

I come up with a solution in which **myshell.sh** take 4 arguments
  `[start_date] [start_time] [end_date] [end_time].`
and script code :

```
#!/bin/bash  
JAR_PATH=/home/vagrant/datatool/datacollector.jar
PID_PATH=/tmp/datacollector-id

#calculate wait time to run the jar
wait=$(($(date -d "$1 $2" "+%s")-$(date "+%s")))
wait_mins=$((wait/60))

#calculate time for which jar file should be executed
run_interval=$(($(date -d "$3 $4" "+%s")-$(date -d "$1 $2" "+%s")))
run_interval_mins=$((run_interval/60))

echo "tool will satrt after $wait_mins"

#wait before running jar file
sleep "$wait_mins"m

#run the jar file
nohup java -jar $JAR_PATH /tmp 2>> /dev/null >> /dev/null &

echo $! > $PID_PATH

#wait for jar execution time
sleep "$run_interval_mins"m

#kill the jar process
PID=$(cat $PID_PATH);
echo "tool process killed"
kill $PID;

echo "program terminated"
```

and I am running the code with command:

```
$ nohup ./myshell.sh 2017-06-08 20:07:00 2017-06-08 20:10:00 >> scriptoutput.txt  2>> /dev/null &
```

and scriptoutput.txt contains:

```
tool will satrt after 3
tool process killed
program terminated
```

Where I need to improve my code?
Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: For Linux/Unix environments, cron would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no wonders: considering your post, you are probably not allowed to modify its source code and recompile it. Thus, *you need an external thing, some other process* what

- starts the jar with a JVM
- stops it
- informs the user about its start and stop.

The simplest way to do that are the

- `at` command (you can start something in the future with it)
- `cron` command (you can periodically can execute commands with it in the background)
- and, the shell scripts.

If it is only a single-time execution, the "`at`" command would be the best.

Learn about the linux shellscripting by googling for "linux shell scripting tutorial". You can have more specific answers about your problem on the http://unix.stackexchange.com .